# Auto Increment Custom data type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using a program which I don't have access to its code, but I do have access to its database in SQLServer 2008.

I'm developing another program to interact with that database but, trying to insert a row with a null id so that it appeared auto-incremented, it threw an Error at the 2nd attempt due to the default value ((0)).

I've found several tables whose Primary Key is a User Defined Data Type called "Autonumeric".

The definition of the data type is:

`CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AutoNumerico] FROM [int] NOT NULL`
[Custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4oXv.png)

This field autoincrements when inserting with the Original program, but it doesn´t have the Identity property.

The creation of the Primary Key is:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbTableName](
    [IDEstrComp] [dbo].[AutoNumerico] NOT NULL,
    ...
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbTableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDEstrComp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]` [Primary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnSK3.png)

**Does this mean that the key is generated in the program?**

**Is there any reason to increment in the program instead of using an auto-increment field in the database?**

Comment: I think it could also be a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) which is incremented in a stored procedure.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu sequence started in 2012 version, this is 2008...

Comment: Also, it might help to see the definition of the data type.

Comment: *Is there any reason?*  When a database generates the key, the calling program needs a system to find and obtain the new key value.  When a program generates the key, it can simply store the value in a variable for later reuse.  Although this is slightly easier to manage (from the program's point of view) I'm not a fan.  Keys are an incredibly important part of a db.  They are much better at generating, managing and handling concurrency that programs.

Comment: Yes, it most likely means that the key is generated in the program. Check also that there are no triggers on this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a stored procedure that inserts into an auxiliar table, deletes the inserted row and returns the @@IDENTITY generated

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spValorAutonumerico]
(
    @Value INT output
)
AS

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO  xAutoNumeric
    (Valor)
    VALUES
    (0)

    SET @Valor = @@IDENTITY

    DELETE FROM xAutoNumeric
    WHERE ID = @Valor
END
```